# 5c restore fails, at the "Waiting for iPhone" stage of restore. Does not start back up.

Tags: iphone

I am trying to restore my 5c, it boots to the charging page, then to the apple logo, after its done this once, and the restore procedure fails, at the pre mentioned stage, with error code 2001, it will then boot straight into recovery mode, I am unable to restore my phone. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

According to the Apple site [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204770), error code **2001** is related to **USB problems**.  Try the following:

1. Use the USB cable that came with the iPhone or a different USB cable that is from Apple directly (not 3rd-party, even if it is MFI)
2. Plug the USB cable into a different port on the computer.  Don't use a USB on a keyboard.
3. Try a different computer.

If all those fail, try the 'Check for hardware issues' on that same Apple site.

.

Comment: I will try that, I am suspecting the battery, since it can't start up under its own power, when it needs to boot up into the new system, it can't,therefore failing the restore, and since its powered off, no power is being provided. Could that be a possibility?

Comment: That did not work either.

Comment: You tried all those options already?  You're still getting the 2001 error?

Comment: Yes. It does not start back up again, it just loops through, charging screen, apple logo screen, and then starts over, after a attempted restore, it boots straight to recovery mode after the charging page, I am going to get a new battery tomorrow, so will report back.

Comment: Is it jailbroken?  Have you tried putting it in DFU mode first?

Comment: Its not no, due to the way its behaving I am not able to put it in DFU mode.

Comment: Any other possible causes for this?